# output linked list to txt file

Tags: c, linked-list, printf

Hello I am trying to export a linked list to a text file but somehow all the time the text file reaches to very big size(5gb)and not opened.

I would be happy if you could see what the problem is and offer me a way to repair her thanks

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
} node;

node* insert(node* head, int num);
void free_list(node *head);
void fprintfList(node *head); 

int main()
{


int num;
int temp;
node *head, *p;
head = NULL;
FILE * MyFile;

do 
{
    printf("Enter numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num) 
    {
        head = insert(head, num);
    }
} while(num);
p = head;

MyFile = fopen("New_File.txt","w");

while(head) 
{
    fprintf(MyFile, "%d\n",head->next);
} 



//fprintfList(head); 
free_list(head);
fclose(MyFile);
return 0;
}




node* insert(node* head, int num) 
{
node *temp, *prev, *next;
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->data = num;
temp->next = NULL;
if(!head){
    head=temp;
} else{
    prev = NULL;
    next = head;
    while(next && next->data<=num){
        prev = next;
        next = next->next;
    }
    if(!next){
        prev->next = temp;
    } else{
        if(prev) {
            temp->next = prev->next;
            prev-> next = temp;
        } else {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }            
    }   
}
return head;
}


void free_list(node *head) 
{
node *prev = head;
node *cur = head;
while(cur) 
{
    prev = cur;
    cur = prev->next;
    free(prev);
}       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(head) 
{
    fprintf(MyFile, "%d\n",head->next);
}
```

Your problem lies here. You loop until `head` is NULL, but never actually change the `head` pointer, hence you'll just loop forever writing the same data out until you run out of disk space. In addition, you're printing the value of the `next` pointer, not actually the data stored in the node.

You first need print the actual data, so change the `fprintf` to:

```
fprintf(MyFile, "%d\n",head->data);
```

Secondly, you actually need to iterate over the list, like follows

```
while(head) 
{
    fprintf(MyFile, "%d\n",head->data);
    head = head->next;
}
```